# Htaccess language detection redirect for all urls

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I´m trying to use the mod_rewrite language detection redirect, however I cannot make my code work. My intention is to make it work for every url, adding the "?language=spanish" at the end of url when visitors are from spanish language.

Here is it:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-Language} ^.*(es).*$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ?language=spanish [L,R=301]
```

Could you please help me out?
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-Language} ^.*(es).*$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !language=spanish
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /$1?language=spanish [L,R=301,QSA]
```

Comment: Hi Jon, I´ve tried with yours but it´s like css or something gets messed up. Maybe the first line is the problem? RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-Language} ^.*(es).*$ [NC]